# animating lines with shapes in canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

will try to be clear here , in this starfeild animation what i want to add is that when the circles originate a pair each should attached by a line to eachother and as the move forward and apart the line will expand and at the point will disappear when the circles move out of the canvas 
anyhelp would be appreciated

```js
function randomRange(minVal, maxVal) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxVal - minVal - 1)) + minVal;
}

function initStars() {
  for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    stars[i] = {
      x: randomRange(-25, 25),
      y: randomRange(-25, 25),
      z: randomRange(1, MAX_DEPTH)
    }
  }
}

function degToRad(deg) {
  radians = (deg * Math.PI / 180) - Math.PI / 2;
  return radians;

}

function animate() {
  var halfWidth = canvas.width / 2;
  var halfHeight = canvas.height / 2;

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    stars[i].z -= 0.2;

    if (stars[i].z <= 0) {
      stars[i].x = randomRange(-25, 25);
      stars[i].y = randomRange(-25, 25);
      stars[i].z = MAX_DEPTH;
    }

    var k = 128.0 / stars[i].z;
    var px = stars[i].x * k + halfWidth;
    var py = stars[i].y * k + halfHeight;

    if (px >= 0 && px <= 1500 && py >= 0 && py <= 1500) {
      var size = (1 - stars[i].z / 32.0) * 5;
      var shade = parseInt((1 - stars[i].z / 32.0) * 750);
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + shade + "," + shade + "," + shade + ")";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(px, py, size, degToRad(0), degToRad(360));
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
}

function animate() {
  var halfWidth = canvas.width / 2;
  var halfHeight = canvas.height / 2;

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    stars[i].z -= 0.2;

    if (stars[i].z <= 0) {
      stars[i].x = randomRange(-25, 25);
      stars[i].y = randomRange(-25, 25);
      stars[i].z = MAX_DEPTH;
    }

    var k = 128.0 / stars[i].z;
    var px = stars[i].x * k + halfWidth;
    var py = stars[i].y * k + halfHeight;

    if (px >= 0 && px <= 1500 && py >= 0 && py <= 1500) {
      var size = (1 - stars[i].z / 32.0) * 5;
      var shade = parseInt((1 - stars[i].z / 32.0) * 750);
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + shade + "," + shade + "," + shade + ")";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(px, py, size, degToRad(0), degToRad(360));
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>

<head>
  <title>stars</title>

  <script src="convergis.js"></script>
  <script>
    MAX_DEPTH = 32;

    var canvas, ctx;
    var stars = new Array(500);

    window.onload = function() {
      canvas = document.getElementById("tutorial");
      if (canvas && canvas.getContext) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        initStars();
        setInterval(animate, 17);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id='tutorial' width='1500' height='1500'>
  
  </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean smth like this? https://jsfiddle.net/arfeo/b2rkzxy9/

```
var MAX_DEPTH = 32;
var canvas, ctx;
var stars = new Array(500);

canvas = document.getElementById("tutorial");

if (canvas && canvas.getContext) {
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  initStars();
  setInterval(animate, 17);
}

function randomRange(minVal, maxVal) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxVal - minVal - 1)) + minVal;
}

function initStars() {
  for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    stars[i] = {
      x: randomRange(-25, 25),
      y: randomRange(-25, 25),
      z: randomRange(1, MAX_DEPTH)
    }
  }
}

function degToRad(deg) {
  radians = (deg * Math.PI / 180) - Math.PI / 2;

  return radians;
}

function animate() {
  var halfWidth = canvas.width / 2;
  var halfHeight = canvas.height / 2;

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < stars.length - 1; i += 1) {
    stars[i].z -= 0.2;

    if (stars[i].z <= 0) {
      stars[i].x = randomRange(-25, 25);
      stars[i].y = randomRange(-25, 25);
      stars[i].z = MAX_DEPTH;
    }

    var k = 128.0 / stars[i].z;
    var px = stars[i].x * k + halfWidth;
    var py = stars[i].y * k + halfHeight;
    var nextPx = stars[i + 1].x * k + halfWidth;
    var nextPy = stars[i + 1].x * k + halfWidth;

    if (px >= 0 && px <= 1500 && py >= 0 && py <= 1500) {
      var size = (1 - stars[i].z / 32.0) * 5;
      var shade = parseInt((1 - stars[i].z / 32.0) * 750);

      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + shade + "," + shade + "," + shade + ")";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(px, py, size, degToRad(0), degToRad(360));
      ctx.fill();

      if (px > 0 && px < canvas.width &&
            py > 0 && py < canvas.height &&
          nextPx > 0 && nextPx < canvas.width &&
          nextPy > 0 && nextPy < canvas.height) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(px, py);
        ctx.lineTo(nextPx, nextPy);
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    }
  }
}
```